# Holomorphic function in a punctured neighbourhood of a disk

Tags: complex-analysis

I need to show that if $f$ is holomorphic at $D_r(z_0)\setminus \{z_0\}$ and $z_0$ is a pole of $f$, then $\exists R>0$ such that $f(D_r(z_0)\setminus \{z_0\})\supset \mathbb{C}\setminus \bar{D_R(0)}$. IOW: $f$ maps punctured neighbourhood of a pole to a neighbourhood of infinity.

My thoughts: If $f$ has a pole at $z_0$, $1/f$ has a removable singularity at $z_0.$ Then $1/f$ can be extended to a holomorphic function in $D_r(z_0)$. I am stuck here. Please help!

I cannot use Riemann mapping theorem yet, if that's useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Extending $1/f$, you have an holomorphic function 
$$D_r(z_0)\longrightarrow\Bbb C.$$
Now, apply the open map theorem.

Comment: how can i use it?

Comment: @math, the image of $D_r(z_0)$ contains a disk centered at 0.

Comment: sorry. I need to show this, but I don't see why is it true?

Comment: @math, is a consequence of the open map theorem: the image is open, $0\in$ image, so exists...

Comment: I am only aware of this open mapping theorem: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_mapping_theorem_(complex_analysis) are you referring to this?